# Why there are so many question marked "on hold" with good number of up vote count

Tags: discussion, on-hold

Why are there post marked as [on hold] but having good number of up vote count. What I understand is once a question is voted up, it certainly have some potential in it. If it was off-topic or does not meet the ask question criteria then what about those people who find it useful. No offense but just trying to understand the reason behind this conflict

Comment: Could it be that the question at first glance seems to be an interesting one, but is put on hold as there are many duplicates on the site already?

Comment: Often these are old questions which were once considered good questions for the site but are now off topic

Comment: In that case it will be marked as `[Duplicate]` NOT `On Hold` if I am right.. I agree that in case it is a duplicate, it does make sense to marked it even if there are up vote count

Comment: recommended reading: [The Trouble With Popularity](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: Well, you only need 15 reputation to upvote something. It's quite easy to get 15 rep without understanding the site at all.

Comment: So the up vote privilege might be assign to people having bit more reputation. All m saying is when a question is voted up it indicates certain potentials to some one and should we not value the same ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Votes don't necessarily reflect appropriateness for the site. Not everything people like, find interesting or is well written is appropriate. While such questions can get a fair amount of upvotes, it does not mean that the question can't be closed/put on hold. (In all honesty, I would not be surprised at all, if a significant part of the voting population is unaware of what is considered to be good on-topic content)

This happens for older questions which once were just fine, but by now no longer meet the site's requirements. But it also happens for new questions which seem interesting or of value, but are ultimately not a good fit.

Comment: +1 for "Votes don't necessarily reflect appropriateness for the site."  This is especially true for questions that qualify for migration.  I'll upvote a question that's well written and then vote to migrate to TeX.SE.  I'll upvote a "recommend a tool or library" question that, as the upvote tooltip says, "shows research effort; it is useful and clear", and still vote to close as off-topic.  The tooltip _doesn't_ say "This question is on-topic for this site."