# What is the preferred action for an "on-hold" question with many "up-votes"?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, on-hold

I asked [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21221411/when-will-gnu-c-support-c11-without-explicitly-asking-for-it/21223733?noredirect=1#21223733) that was put *"on-hold"* during the about 5 hours. On the other hand the question was quite popular with about 10 up-votes in one day.

While I (can) agree with the reason the question was should be put on hold ("that is a question better put to the g++ development team"), the question itself seems to be of some interest for the general public. Therefore I now wonder, what should I do with the question?

- an edit is not feasible, because it will not alter the real question
- a comment I did, but does not change the opinions "ask the g++-team"
- should I delete it, despite the public interest in it? I somehow do not like this idea, maybe because I do not agree totally that the question has no place on SO. Delete it anyway? Is this a case like [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196574/213481)?
- should I just leave it "on hold", which leaves me with a feeling of "an open parenthesis"...

Comment: FWIW the question has been reopened.

Answer (score 5):

You can't delete it because it has upvoted answers. So just let it be. It doesn't really do any harm. And if you think it has useful content but improving it is not possible, just leave it like it is.

Comment: I see. "on-hold" will become "closed". gotya.